# how can I do a git pull in the gitg / gitx visual tool?

Tags: git, git-remote, gitx, gitg

I can do a push using gitg and push my code to the remote master branch but I can't see any option to do a git **pull**.

I am on Ubuntu 10 and 11

Comment: Your first two sentences are contradicting. »I can do a pull, but I can't see any option to pull« say what?

Comment: good point.  I meant push in the first instance.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You cannot directly pull from `git gui`, but given than a `pull` is a `fetch` followed by a `merge`,  you can fetch the remote (in the remote menu and `fetch from`), and then merge the remote branch into yours (Merge menu and `Local merge`, select `tracking branch`).

Comment: This sounds perfect!  Unfortunately I cannot find the remote menu or fetch_from :(

Comment: Are you sure you're in the git gui? (`File` menu -> `start Git Gui`, or `git gui` from command line) The gitk doen't have this.

Comment: thanks CharlesB :) I don't find that in gitg on Ubuntu 11.04 but I am trying a download of 'cola git gui' to see if that helps...

Comment: Ahh yes, 'git gui' is a different tool from the 'gitg' that I have been using and once I downloaded it (again that's 'Cola git gui' for anyone searching).  I will update your answer and also check it as the answer.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: mmh sorry I thought you meant gitk

Answer (score 2):

In gitg 0.2.4, you cannot pull directly, so you also fetch and merge:

- fetch by going in the repository properties, select the remote repo and cli
- display all branches of the remote, and merge the branch you want (`origin/master` most of the time) by right-clicking on the tip of the branch