# How do you push code with gitg?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, push, gitg

I can do everything else I need but with the GUI I cannot seem to figure out how to pull or push code. Pushing is more important in this case, anyone know how?

Comment: With regards to pulling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299237/how-can-i-do-a-git-pull-in-the-gitg-gitx-visual-tool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out, not too difficult, just have to right click on the branch name when you are looking at your commit history

Comment: in Gitg 3.16 I can not find a push option in that menu.

Comment: for 3.17 I can confirm that there is no such option.

Comment: I only see an option for fetching in gitg 3.30 on manjaro and the authentication for that is somehow broken. Frankly, just alt-tab to a terminal and push from there with a properly set up ssh key.

Answer (score 20):

Anyone looking for this feature in gitg 3.14: I got confirmation from a developer that it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: No, but here is the upstream issue: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763355

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but... Why hasn't it been implemented yet? it's a pretty essential feature

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 3.24 in Fedora 26 and it is not implemented there either.

Answer (score 5):

On the history tab, right click on the name of the tracking branch

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, couldn't find it otherwise

Comment: The screenshot is probably from older version of gitg (0.2.X), which supported checkout, push, cherry-pick and many other useful features, that don't work in the current version of gitg.

Comment: According to the NEWS file on Gitg's source code (https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/tree/NEWS), branch push was a feature regression on version 0.3.1 as a part of its rewrital. To this day, it has yet to be brought back, sadly.

Comment: Oh, apparently it's been recently written and sent to a patch, hopefully it'll be added into the next version of Gitg. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763355.

Answer (score 1):

Push action is available starting from version 3.32.0

[See NEWS file in "Release 3.32.0" gitg commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gitg/-/commit/e0dbd9b31cd8fac546ddb928a9e594e6095b5d5e)

Answer (score 0):

Create on `.git/hooks` a file named `post-commit` and insert this code

```
#!/bin/bash
git push -u origin master
```

and turn this into a executable script

```
chmod 755 post-commit
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official project roadmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/RoadMap), it is a feature in todo state;
the target release is 0.3 so I assume this table it is not updated so this project is poorly maintained: we can imagine real gnome coders do not use GUIs :)

[image]

Answer (score -4):

You have to clone a repository previously. 
For example:

`git clone https://github.com/manuelkiessling/NodeBeginnerBook.git`

Once cloned, go into the downloaded repository and execute `gitk`