# Git pull and push not working (using gitg client)

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, bitbucket, gitg

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm using a Bitbucket private repository. I installed git on my Ubuntu machine and then installed `gitg`. I've lived on windows all my life and getting used to the terminal is frankly very difficult. This is also my first time working with git (I've used svn before).

**Pushing**

I am able to clone the repository to a local folder on my machine using `git clone`. (Via the terminal) Afterwards, I make a change and then using `gitg` I can see the change and commit it. The commit however does not work as the changes are not reflected on the bitbucket site.

I've looked at some other questions on this site and they say that I can right click on the selected branch and then push to make the commit happen on the server. Is this the correct way to push a commit using `gitg`?

**Pulling**

Moving on, I cannot figure out how to get the latest version down to my machine. How do I perform a pull request? Previous answers to questions here said that I must use the `fetch` command in the `remote` menu, but I can't find the `remote` menu in my gitg interface.

Any advice on this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pushing**

Yes that would be correct way to commit and push using gitg.

**Pulling**

Gitg does not support pulling directly. You have to do a fetch and a merge.

This answer:

[how can I do a git pull in the gitg / gitx visual tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310542/1368726)

Describes how you have to go into the repository properties, select the remote repo and then `fetch`.
Merging is supposedly done by displaying all remote branches and then selecting the remote branch you want to merge with by right-clicking and selecting `merge`

*Note*
I do not use gitg myself so the answer is based on reading the scarce amount of documentation i could dig up.

Comment: I use the command line for everything but comparing versions and resolving conflicts. I prefer the control this gives me and I find it easier to write "git push master" and "git pull master" or "git fetch origin" followed by "git merge FETCH_HEAD master"